# Nx Nest библиотека не создаётся вместе с eslint

Tags: nestjs, eslint, nx

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Не могу создать библиотеку Nx Nest.js вместе с esLint.
Кто сталкивался и что можно сделать?

```
NX   isEslintConfigSupported is not a function
```

Comment: [Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/385375)